# Asp.Net Core 3.1 role based authorization for Web Api does not work

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-3.1

I use the IdentityServer4 that comes with Asp.Net Core 3.1 to implement role based authorization.

On debugging, I see that claim `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` is correctly set to "Administrator" on entering the server Web Api call. But,
`[Authorize (Roles = "Administrator")]` for the Web Api always fails returning 403 error. Note that the simple `[Authorize]` works fine.

I went through debugging steps described in https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/14944 without success. Appreciate if you can help to make role based authorization work.

Code snippet:

```
AddOpenIdConnect(IdentityServerConstants.ProtocolTypes.OpenIdConnect, opt =>
            {
                opt.Authority = "http://localhost:44369";
                opt.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                opt.ClientId = "mvc";
                opt.ClientSecret = "secret";
                opt.ResponseType = "code";

                opt.SaveTokens = true;
                opt.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                opt.Scope.Add("roles");
                opt.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("roles", "role");
                opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                    RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                };
            }).
```

Decoded JWT below:

```
{
  "nbf": 1606797785,
  "exp": 1606801385,
  "iss": "https://localhost:44369",
  "aud": "BaselineAPI",
  "client_id": "Baseline",
  "sub": "38ba2f2e-100d-eb11-ae75-00f48da696da",
  "auth_time": 1606752334,
  "idp": "local",
  "role": "Administrator",
  "scope": [
    "openid",
    "profile",
    "BaselineAPI"
  ],
  "amr": [
    "pwd"
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Replacing the Role with Policy based authorization works.

Add this to Startup.cs:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options => { 
        options.AddPolicy("IsAdmin", policy => { policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"); });
    });
```

Add this to your Api method:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "IsAdmin")]
```

Comment: Have you inspected the JWT using a tool like https://jwt.io/ to ensure that the roles claim is in the JWT and contains the data you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Yes, it does show the role claim. I've posted the JWT in the question

Answer (score 0):

The name of the Role claim name in IdentityServer is not the same as the name of the Role claim in ASP.NET Core. To map this you need to add this code:

```
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
            };
```

If you also want to add additional claims, you need to explicitly map them into the local user ClaimsPrincipal using:

```
            options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("claimname", "claimname");
```

By default these claims are not included in the user object.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I do have this but still it does not work. I've added the snippet to my original post